# ImageMagick create large blank image without using lots of disk

Tags: imagemagick, png

How can I create a large blank image with ImageMagick without using gigabytes of disk space?

```
convert -debug All -size 100000x100000 canvas:white big_white.png
```

This takes at least 8 GB of disk space since it won't run with ImageMagick policy disk set to 8 GB.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly, please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I thought the title is pretty self-explanatory...

Comment: I’m trying to understand your further purpose. What are you going to do next?

Comment: The point is to create a very large image to test OpenCV's handling of such files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to create a 100,000x100,000 blank PNG, I would recommend `libvips` to you. It is very frugal with resources compared to **ImageMagick**.

So, to create a 100000x100000 pixel black PNG in Terminal:

```
vips black black.png 100000 100000 --bands 3
```

takes 300s on my machine and uses 227MB of RAM. I tested with:

```
/usr/bin/time -l vips black black.png 100000 100000 --bands 3
```

If you insist on making that white, you can invert it:

```
vips invert black.png white.png
```

which takes 360s on my machine and uses 406MB of RAM.

---

By comparison, **ImageMagick** needs 3,300 seconds and ?? GB of RAM to do the same:

```
/usr/bin/time -l convert -size 100000x100000 canvas:white big_white.png
```

By the way, you should be more specific about whether you want a greyscale or a colour PNG, whether a palletised image is acceptable or not, and whether you want 8-bits/sample or 16-bits/sample.

Comment: Thanks. I had heard of vips before for large images but it did not have an official conda installation.

Comment: Creation for PNG, JPEG, and TIFF is faster and produces significantly smaller images by enabling compression.